# Nested query to unknown level GraphQL

Tags: graphql

I have a tree structure. Let's say Folder for example.

How do I query nested queries to N level using GraphQL.

Let's take an example as I have following properties in class.

```
public class DocumentField
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<DocumentField> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

Server side is designed in a way that if children are there then it will include as children. But graphql layer is restricting it because my query which is following.

Following query will not bring result of children.

```
query ($folderId: Int!) {
                              folder(folderId: $folderId) {
                                id,
                                name
                              }
                            }
```

Following query gives error as: nested query Field children of type DocumentFieldICollection must have a sub selection

```
query ($folderId: Int!) {
                          folder(folderId: $folderId) {
                            id,
                            name,
                            children
                          }
                        }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

GraphQL does not allow to query such recursive structure down to all levels dynamically. You have to explicitly specify how many levels that you want to query. For example , to query to down 4 levels , the query looks liked :

```
query ($folderId: Int!) {
  folder(folderId: $folderId) {
    id
    name
    children {
       id 
       name
       children{
          id
          name
          children{
            id
            name
          }
       }
    }
  }
 }
```

You can use [`fragment`](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/91#issuecomment-254895093) to reduce some duplication in this query. For details , please see [this](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/91).

Comment: Oh. now this first line is really frustrating. I have no idea how many nested levels are there from client side.